# Jenkins rewrites URL to root when setting up behind HAProxy

Tags: jenkins, haproxy

I am trying to set up a Jenkins behind my HAProxy. These are parts of my HAProxy configutaration file which I think are relevant (if the entire file is needed please let me know)

```
...

acl jenkins_host path_beg  /jenkins/ #front end

...

...

use_backend jenkins_backend if jenkins_host

...
backend jenkins_backend
    server jenkins1 10.62.194.6:8080
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(Host)]
    http-request del-header X-Forwarded-Port
...
```

I used the instructions at the following [resource](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+HAProxy) to create the above.

When I visit `< mydevopshost > / jenkins/` I can see the URL rewriting to:
`http://devopshost/login?from=%2Fjenkins%2F` and a `503 Service Unavailable error`

Comment: An application behind a reverse proxy like HAProxy typically needs to to be aware of what its base URL is supposed to be, if that can't be determined automatically, and a path prefix match makes that determination impossible. 
I believe the linked Q&A answers this question.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you were correct. The linked question led me down the correct path. I had to set the context path of my jenkins instance. If you submit an answer I will accept it as the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: This community prefers not to post answers to questions that have already been answered elsewhere on the site, but rather to link to the already existing question.  I've cast a vote to close this as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: It might be worth noting that you usually can’t use the HA part of HAProxy’s features with Jenkins. You can only have one instance of Jenkins running against the same JENKINS_HOME at a time, otherwise you’ll end up with problems such as multiple builds if you have any jobs that are triggered on a schedule or by SCM polling.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Ah alright.. I'll accept the prompt as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @gareth_bowles thanks for the info.. I think for now current setup is sufficient.. This mostly for local development work so far only me and few others use this Jenkins instance for now